# Primefaces: exporting data to Excel from custom table

Tags: excel, jsf-2, primefaces

Previously I had problems with customizing p:dataTable (freezing columns, merging headers is not implemented in my Primefaces version 3.4.1) so I decided to make table manually by using ui:repeat:

```
<h:form id="MY_FORM">
    ...
    <div class="ui-datatable">
        <table id="resultTable">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.columns}" var="column">
                          ...
```

It is all ok with my new table, but now I need an advice: which is an easiest way to create button for exporting this table data to Excel as p:dataExporter requires p:dataTable as target:

```
<p:commandButton value="Export To Excel" ajax="false">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="resultTable" fileName="results" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I've tried to use [DataTables TableTools extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/), but maybe exists something without using flash and JavaScript customizing

Comment: Your table is not a jsf component so it will never be recognized by the exporter (via the id). But even if you make it into a jsf component, you have to fully customize the exporter.

Comment: It looks like a to complicated solution to me

Comment: Yep, trying to use FlyingSaucer (xhtml -> pdf, JSF independent) might work to.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832880/xmlresourceload-throws-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-system